# is lspci command return memory mapped io locations of registers from /sys/bus/pci/device/***

Tags: linux, io, intel, pci, memory-mapping

I have intel system. running linux. On my system when I run `sudo lspci -v` command it gives me something like this for wireless network card[image]

In the image it says for wireless network card something like this `Memory at c0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]`

I want to know is this the memory location for Memory-Mapped-IO for pci wireless network card?

and the lines afterwards says something like `Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3`
and `Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit`. Can any one please tell is c8 and d0 respectively are the offset address values from base value of `c0700000` (from above) for setting these capabilities to wireless network card. I have pci based wireless in my laptop.

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: c0700000 is the physical address of the MMIO space of the device. c8 and d0 are offsets in the PCIe config space of the device, not the MMIO space. Since lspci is a standard tool, it can only display standard capabilities; it has no way to interpret the contents of device-specific MMIO space.

Comment: @prl so `c0700000` is the base address where the IO  Memory mapping starts. To read RX ring and TX ring. Do I have to use intel datasheet for the device to get packets from RX ring and TX ring so do I need datasheet to get offset values of RX register and TX register?